# esta bien el procedimiento con un output (phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, stored-procedure, if

que tal? tengo una duda quiero hacer un procedimiento para que el final me de un resultado 0 o 1 segun el numero de resultado de mi tabla users el procedimiento es este:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Coretec_ConfirmUser(IN p_user_mail VARCHAR(150),OUT p_result INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE rows INT;
        SET rows=SELECT COUNT(users.user_id) FROM users WHERE users.user_mail=p_user_mail;
        IF (rows>=1) THEN
            SET p_result=1;
        ELSE
            SET p_result=0;
        END IF;

        SELECT p_result;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

al final me vota este error:
Error

consulta SQL:

CREATE PROCEDURE Coretec_ConfirmUser(IN p_user_mail VARCHAR(150),OUT p_result INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE rows INT

MySQL ha dicho:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema creo que está en la declaración de la variable y en la asignación.  Por favor prueba de hacerlo de esta forma:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Coretec_ConfirmUser(IN p_user_mail VARCHAR(150),OUT p_result INT)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @rows = COUNT(users.user_id) FROM users WHERE users.user_mail=p_user_mail;
        IF (@rows > 0) THEN
            SET p_result=1;
        ELSE
            SET p_result=0;
        END IF;

        SELECT p_result;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

¡Suerte!